# Why kafka create stream as most once

Tags: apache-kafka

I know kafka has a limit that each consumer can only create message streams at most once. (Or it will throw MessageStreamsExistException). But I want to know why. Since I think that, If we creating a stream more than one time we have to do nothing but trigger the kafka to rebalance again like we create the stream at the first time. So why does this restrict come up.

Comment: You mean each "producer" can only create message streams at most once?

Comment: @DimaLih In here, I mean the consumer. But if the producer also had the same restriction I want to know why too.